# EVENTS on MYSQL aren't working on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem when creating an event in MySql.

A few days ago I bought a server and added all the information of my pages including the database.

I want to execute an UPDATE every 24 hours in a certain table called: NEWAHORROSH

that contains the data:

```
CREATE TABLE newahorrosh (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
user_id int not null,
capital_real float (11,2) not null,
interests float (11,2) not null,
capital_total float (11,2) as (capital_real + interest)
);
```

The code of my event is:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT CalculoIntereses
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO
BEGIN
    IF (newahorrosh.capital_real> 1 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <500) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET interests = interests + ((capital_real * 3 * 1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real> 5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET interests = interests + ((capital_real * 4 * 1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real> 1001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <5000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET interests = interests + ((capital_real * 5 * 1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real> 5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <15000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET interests = interests + ((capital_real * 6 * 1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real> 15001) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET interests = interests + ((capital_real * 7 * 1/36000));
    END IF;

END |

DELIMITER;
```

The event is created perfectly without errors but when the time arrives in which the information must be updated, it is not executed. I already noticed that the Schedule of events was on in my phpmyadmin.

I repeat it does not throw me error when creating the event but when I open my event in my phpmyadmin it shows me an X of errors in my code

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMjiB.png)

I would greatly appreciate the help because I have almost 2 weeks trying to solve this. A thousand thanks for your time.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reflect any of the tags that you used.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for your comment buddy. I have updated my question.

Comment: "The event is created perfectly without errors but when the time arrives in which the information must be updated, it is not executed." Did you read the MySQL manual about `CREATE EVENT`? "**This statement creates and schedules a new event. The event will not run unless the Event Scheduler is enabled**” For information about checking Event Scheduler status and enabling it if necessary, see Section 24.4.2, [“Event Scheduler Configuration”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-configuration.html).  "

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for your comment : "...I already noticed that the Schedule of events was ON in my phpmyadmin".

Comment: You sure the MySQL user which you used to created the event has also UPDATE privlleges for the newahorrosh  table which is used in the event? Besides you also might want to add `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` otherwise the event will be a one time event when it does run.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Once again thanks for your time, and Yes i am checking the user's privileges and the ROOT (which is what i am using) has a type:Global, privileges: All Privileges, allowed: Yes..

as far as I am concern ON COMPLETION PRESERVE is used for save the event once is complete however my event will be running for a Year so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does `newahorrosh.capital_real` come from when the event is executed?

As there is currently no `ELSE` statement and no value to compare against, all checks fail and nothing is being executed.

The SQL inside the event body is only evaluated *at runtime*, that means when the event occurs. When defining the event the SQL is *not* evaluated and might commit even with syntax errors in the code.

So you will never see an error in phpMyAdmin, even if the content of your event is total crap.

You need to run a `SELECT` to obtain some value to compare against in your `IF` statement.

Or you write an `UPDATE` statement and use `IF()` or `CASE` to dynamically calculate the new value for each row, like so:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT CalculoIntereses
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO
BEGIN
UPDATE newahorrosh SET interests = interests + (1/36000 * capital_real * 
  (CASE 
    WHEN capital_real < 500   THEN 3
    WHEN capital_real < 1000  THEN 4
    WHEN capital_real < 5000  THEN 5
    WHEN capital_real < 15000 THEN 6
    ELSE 7
  END)
);
END |
DELIMITER;
```

By the way: You also have a typo / gap in your inital `IF` statement:

```
newahorrosh.capital_real> 5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000
```

I guess you wanted to write:

```
newahorrosh.capital_real> 501 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000
```

So even if your code would be working as intended, it would still not work for values between 501 and 1000. Nothing would happen to values in this range.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer Everything is working fine i changed the 24 Hour for 1 minute